# Java: Multi-Indexed Sorted Cache or a SortedMap with Index Access

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

So here is the problem I am facing, I'm trying to implement a HashMap using an Id as key, and an object pointer as the value.

Within each object, there are a couple of Integers, let's say they represent investment amounts in various categories defined in the object.

However, I would like to be able to sort the investment amount in a particular category and access the Nth element, while accessing the key and object. So it has to be indexed by each each investment amount.

Example:
Id=1, Object:{ Gas=2000, Tech=5000, Bank=1000 }
Id=2, Object:{ Gas=1000, Tech=8000, Bank=2000 }
Id=3, Object:{ Gas=4000, Tech=6000, Bank=3000 }

So, I want to be able to do lookups by Ids to the object (easy). But I also want to be able to do something like Gas[0] to get the top investment for gas (i.e. Id=3), Tech[2] to get the 3rd highest investment for tech (i.e. Id=1).

What kind of data structure should be used for something like this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [java.util.SortedSe](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html)t with a custom [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for each additional index you want.

```
Map<Integer, MyClass> byId = new HashMap<Integer, MyClass>();
SortedSet<MyClass> byGas = new TreeSet<MyClass>(new MyGasComparator());
SortedSet<MyClass> byTech = new TreeSet<MyClass>(new MyTechComparator()); 
...

class MyGasComparator implements Comparator<MyClass> {
    @override
    public int compare(MyClass a, MyClass b) {
        int r = a.getGas() - b.getGas();
        if (r != 0) {
            return r;
        }

        // gas is equal, ensure fixed order
        return a.getId() - b.getId();
    }
}

...
```

With the comparator shown above, `byGas().first()` will be the object with the biggest gas value, and both `byGas.iterator()` and `byGas.toArray()` will return the objects ordered by Gas in descending order.  Just swap a and b in the comparator to reverse the ordering.

Also, consider encapsulating the index maps in another class that is responsible for adding, removing and looking up values for the various index types.